# are there any special conditions with '*' character in full text search

Tags: sql-server-2005, full-text-search, containstable

i am using sql server 2005 i have a stored procedure which searches database with containstable method the problem is when i search some prefix with `'*'` character i can't see the records which have full word just records with only prefixes. for example i search `'some'` then set my variable to `'some*'` and i have `'some'` and `'something'` records in my database but result is only the record with 'some' is there a special condition with `'*'` character

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've just forgot to quote your search text: you should be searching for CONTAINSTABLE(...,'"some*"') and you might be using CONTAINSTABLE(...,'some*') instead. In a latter case full text search does not treat '*' as a wild card symbol (according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142492(SQL.90).aspx)).

Comment: no i'm not searching with quotes i m printing my variable to control in the sql and always just 'some*' is printed

Comment: Could you please provide a code sample of how you do the search, i.e. the query with CONTAINSTABLE?

Comment: Sorry that project suspended for now i m developing some more important projects for now but i ll try to send you a my code as soon as possible